# Can someone point out the flaw in my proof of AC?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, fake-proofs

I have a fake proof of the axiom of countable choice. Obviously it is not correct, but I cannot see my flaw. Forgive me, I am only learning set theory.

Let $\{A_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ be a countable collection of nonempty sets. Since the axiom of finite choice is a theorem in ZF, there is a choice function $f_n : \{A_n\} \to A_n$ for every $n$. Let $f = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} f_n$. Then $f$ is a choice function on $\{A_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unless each $A_n$ is a singleton (or at least all but finitely many are singletons), there are many [read: more than one] choice functions from each $A_n$. This means that you had to **choose** each $f_n$, which is precisely where you appeal to the axiom of countable choice.

For example, if $A_0=\{x,y\}$ do you take $f_0$ to be the function which chooses $x$ or the one which chooses $y$?

Comment: Mmmmmmm subtle.

Comment: Well, at first. Sure. After a while it becomes obvious, and the *really* subtle things start to appear. Oh how I miss the axiom of choice sometimes. :-)

Comment: An interesting question is whether it matters whether or not f0 is stable. If it returns x the first time and y the second, do things break? I think no.

Comment: This might be something more suitable for fuzzy set theory. In classical set theory functions are concrete sets, they can't just change their minds about the output.

Comment: @Joshua: I forgot to ping in my previous comment, sorry. :-)

Comment: It is interesting because the existence of a non-deterministic and not-necessarily-stable fo is trivially proved.

Comment: @Joshua: I'm not sure that I understand.

Comment: fo(x) → ∃z ∈ x where z is unbound. Can be used for proofs requiring fo to exist wherever it's return is irrelevant.

Comment: @Joshua: This is not a valid definition for a function.

Comment: @Joshua:  A function is a set of ordered pairs.  Either $(\{x, y\}, x) \in f$, or $(\{x, y\}, y) \in f$.

Comment: To add on what @Kevin wrote, *exactly one* of these is in $f$, otherwise it is not a choice function from $\{x,y\}$.